# Recommend me a CSS/JS compressor

Tags: css, javascript, compression

There are scripts to compress CSS on-demand like [these](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/3-ways-to-compress-css-files-using-php).

Have you stumbled upon something similar for javascripts? Also, any recommendations regarding CSS and JS compression are more than welcome. What methods do you use, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most used CSS compressor is [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/). It supports both JS and CSS.

Talking about JS, [Google Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) offers a more powerful set of features compared to YUI Compressor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use gzip compression. This will bring you much more benefits than the standard compression. Also have in mind that compressing some JS files may bring you troubles. Last year I used internet by broadband connection(GSM network) where the provider`s proxy compressed all the content to lower the bandwidth and  this causes me troubles with some sites so test everything you compressed.

Please post and update what optimisation method you choose and what was the benefit.

Comment: +1, gzip should ALWAYS be the first step; minifying will only save a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) has one, so does [Microsoft](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/34488).